# How to make a slide of images in html?

Tags: css

I have make a slide in a div but i cant use perspective with marquee. :| and i want the images to go from left to right. Any idea what i can use instead of marquee?
This is my HTML code:

`<div class="general">
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right">
        <img src="img1.jpg" id="ima"/><!-- img src="img2.jpg" id="ima"/><img src="img3.jpg" id="ima"/><img src="img4.jpg" id="ima"/><img src="img5.jpg" id= "ima"/></marquee>
</div>`

And this is my CSS:

```
    .general{
background: #000fff;
position:absolute;
left:300px;
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
border: 2px solid red;
-moz-transform: perspective( 600px );
perspective-origin: 10% 10%;
-moz-perspective:150px;
-moz-perspective-origin: 10% 10%;}


#ima{width: 200px;height: 150px;}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "i want the images to go from left to right"?  As in flip?

Comment: to scroll from the left side of the div to the right side of the div

Comment: First, you need to get rid of your ID tags on all imgs and use a class instead.  Also, it is currently doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/aB2uX/ ?